# Android: Problems downloading images and converting to bitmaps

Tags: android, networking, bitmap

I am working on an application that downloads images from a url. The problem is that only some images are being correctly downloaded and others are not.
First off, here is the problem code:

```
public Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;
     try {
         response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
     } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        Log.i(LOG_FILE, "client protocol exception");
         return null;
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.i(LOG_FILE, "IOE downloading image");
            return null;
     } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(LOG_FILE, "Other exception downloading image");
            return null;
     }

     // Convert images from stream to bitmap object
     try {
         Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
         if(image==null)
             Log.i(LOG_FILE, "image conversion failed");
         return image;
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.i(LOG_FILE, "Other exception while converting image");
         return null;
     }
}
```

So what I have is a method that takes the url as a string argument and then downloads the image, converts the HttpResponse stream to a bitmap by means of the BitmapFactory.decodeStream method, and returns it. The problem is that when I am on a slow network connection (almost always 3G rather than Wi-Fi) some images are converted to null--not all of them, only some of them. Using a Wi-Fi connection works perfectly; all the images are downloaded and converted properly.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Or better, how can I fix this? How would I even go about testing to determine the problem? Any help is awesome; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the JPEG decoder. There are two solutions. Either you download the entire image in a byte[] array using a ByteInputStream and then decode the array (this is what I do in [code.google.com/p/shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves).) Another solution is to create a wrapper InputStream as shown below:

```
public class PatchInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

  public PatchInputStream(InputStream in) {
    super(in);
  }

  public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
    long m = 0L;
    while (m < n) {
      long _m = in.skip(n-m);
      if (_m == 0L) break;
      m += _m;
    }
    return m;
  }

}
```

Comment: what is m and what is n? I have some problems understanding the code sample maybe some longer variable names would help and maybe a comment or two. Also do you have a link to the bug request on this issue or is this is a general problem that can not be solved in a future version of the jpeg decoder?

Comment: Thank you very much Romain Guy! I would have never figured this out without your help.

For anyone else that comes across this, the first solution Romain Guy mentioned can be found in this class of his program: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/util/ImageUtilities.java

Answer (score 0):

Even with a WiFi connection some bitmaps (in particular .BMPs) will not be decoded. It's just a buggy decoder that can not deal with delays. If you search stackoverflow you will find some other solutions such as wrapping the HTTP stream in a buffered http entity. That works but depending on image size can take up a lot of memory. For our commerical product we ended up downloading the http stream to sdcard and then using Bitmapfactory on the dowloaded file. It's somewhat slower but 100% reliable.